# How to produce a p2wsh transaction with bitcoin-cli?

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness

With the impending adoption of segregated witness, users reliant on the bitcoin-cli API would require to reconstruct new methods to re-produce more efficient transactions. Is there some guide out there to learn how to produce a p2wsh transaction based off a conventional p2sh transaction?

Comment: related: [Segregated Witness Development Guide](https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/)

Comment: Only outputs sent to a SegWit address/script can be spent using SegWit inputs. So the real question is how to establish that address (see Andrew's answer below).

Answer (score 2):

If a P2SH address is already in your wallet, you can use the `addwitnessaddress` RPC command to get the P2SH-P2WSH version of that address and have it added to your wallet for tracking.